How can I pass optional type from C++ to Cython?
I'm trying to pass an optional argument from C++ to Cython files.
I don't know how to write it in .pxd and .pyx file:
[C++]
std::optional<std::shared_ptr<CPP_MyObject>> cpp_find_value();

[Work.pxd]
shared_ptr[CPP_MyObject] cpp_find_value()   # fix me

[Work.pyx]
def python_find_value(self):    # fix me
    cdef shared_ptr[CPP_MyObject] cpp_object = self.thisptr.get().cpp_find_value()
    cdef Python_MyObject python_object = Python_MyObject("0")
    python_object.thisptr = cpp_object
    return python_object


So recently, I found the answer for passing optional value from C++ to Cython Interface. And this is a more elaborated code.
In Work.pxd file
In the Work.pxd file, there's a feature in libcpp.optional that allows you to wrap your C++ data types with optional.
from libcpp.optional cimport optional
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr

cdef extern from "your_cpp_header.h":
    optional[shared_ptr[CPP_MyObject]] cpp_find_value()

In Work.pyx file
In the Work.pyx file, you can receive the result of find_value() as an optional C++ data type. With this, you can check if the value exists using .has_value(). If a value is present, you can insert it into a Python object pointer using .value() and return the Python object.
If no value is present, simply return None.
def python_find_value(self):
    cdef Python_MyObject python_object = Python_MyObject("0")
    cdef optional[shared_ptr[CPP_MyObject]] cpp_object = self.thisptr.get().cpp_find_value()
    
    if cpp_object.has_value():
       python_object.thisptr = cpp_object.value()
       return python_object
    return None


You can use it, simply import optional from libcpp.optional:
from libcpp.optional cimport optional

optional[shared_ptr[CPP_MyObject] cpp_find_value()

and then you can get value of optional by using has_value and value:
cdef shared_ptr[CPP_MyObject] some_ptr
if cpp_object.has_value():
    some_ptr = cpp_object.value()

Please see the Cython optional code on GitHub if you want more information.
